# Container: Vector class.... Slow

Tags: c++, performance, vector, containers

Could anybody explain why, in vector container, push_back operation is usually slower?
I hear some people say that, but can't find the reason why it is a bit slower.

As a beginner, I would like use vector and push_back but do I other options for better performance? Please let me know. Thanks,

Comment: Please note that `std::vector` only *manages* the objects you put into it. It adds, removes, modify, etc. the elements that it contains. However, most of the work done, most notably copy operations, is done by the objects that the vector contains. Thus it is mostly not in `std::vector` itself that is slow but in the operations, that is that of the objects the `std::vector` contains, it uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you append or insert an item into a `std::vector` there may not be enough room to store it. This causes the vector to allocate enough storage to hold all elements and copies them into the new block of memory. If you are storing objects by value instead of by pointer this a complete copy will be made. For complex types this may be involved and include additional allocations and copying. In situations like this performance can be impacted depending on the size of the vector. For large vectors the performance hit will be much more noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

A vector stores its objects in a contiguous array. It allocates a certain amount of space (its *capacity*) to contain the objects; when the number of objects (its *size*) is about to exceed the capacity, it allocates a larger space and copies (or moves) the existing objects across.

This can take some time. To avoid it, and guarantee that `push_back` and `insert` don't need to reallocate, you can call `reserve` to allocate a large enough block for your needs beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The `push_back` operation is not always slower. It has constant complexity (amortized time). The only time it is slower, is if reallocation occurs. One of the useful things about `std::vector` is that you can always add objects to the vector, regardless of the size. Let's the vector's capacity is 10 and there are 10 objects in the vector, then reallocation occurs to make the vector bigger. Usually, the vector size is doubled and the objects are copied into the new vector which is a slower operation.